# Nginx proxy-pass to other domain extracting domain part from URI

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I'm trying to use Nginx as a proxy server which should redirect all requests to different domains based on the URI parameters.

Say we have two servers org1-domain.com and org2-domain.com. The incoming request is `mynginxproxy.com/api/org2/users`. In this case, Nginx should proxy the request to the `org2-domain.com`.

Here's my Nginx config file:

```
    user nginx;
    worker_processes  1;
    events {
      worker_connections  10240;
    }
    http {
      server {
          listen 8080 ssl;
          server_name  nginx-proxy;
          location ^/\w*/(.*)/.*$ {
            proxy_pass  https://$1-domain.com:8080;
          }
      }
    }
```

So I'm using a regex in the location directive in order to get `org` parameter from the URI and use it in the `proxy_pass` directive. But I'm always getting this error:

```
host not found in upstream "-domain.com" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:15
```

I also tried other options for regex in the location directive:

- `location ~ ^/\w*/\w*/(.*)/(.*)$ {`
- `location ~* /(.*)$ {`
- `location ~* /(.*)$ {`

But in all those cases I'm always getting the same `host not found` error.

I also tried to use rewrite rules instead of proxy_pass but in this case, Nginx just returns me a 302 redirect response which is not suitable for my case.

BTW proxy_pass without regex works fine if I'm redirecting directly to the `org2-domain.com`:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass  https://org2-domain.com:8080;
}
```

But I need somehow to extract org from the URI and construct the DNS name for proxy_pass directive.

Comment: Location you show in your question isn't a regex location (without `~` or `~*` modifier). And I think you omit some important configuration parts from the location you've shown in your question, most likely some rewrite rules. Show your actual configuration, please.

Comment: There no rewrite rules in the location directive. I'm only omitting ssl rules because they're not relevant to the question. Also, I tried to use ~ and ~* in the location directive but still getting the same error.

Comment: Whatever is the cause of `$1` variable appears empty, your configuration definitely won't work without `~` (or `~*`) location modifier and `resolver` able to resolve `*-domain.com` being defined. Usually that kind or errors appears when you got another regex matching operation in your location, getting `$1` emptied after it. I don't see anything in your config that could imply such an effect; however, the common workaround is to use named captures to save the captured group value in a named variable:`location ^/\w+/(?<prefix>[-\w]+)/ { proxy_pass  https://$prefix-domain.com:8080; }`